# PDFBox insert images inline with TEXT

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox for the first time to generate a PDF. I have a text document which consists of a series of about 40 multi-choice questions generated by my java program. Some of the questions have associated small images which need to be inserted above the question.
For this reason I am converting the text document to a PDF and hope to insert the images on that.

I have managed to insert an image into the PDF document but it underlay’s the text like a background.
I want to place the images in line with the text (as in word format text box, inline).
It seems the insert image classes need an absolute position which will depend on the position of the text.

How can I know where to draw my image?

for info PDFBox 2.0.7.jar

```
import ExamDatabase.ReadInputFile;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory;//???look up
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType3Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDInlineImage;

/**
 *
 * @author Steve carr
 */
public class HelloWorldPdf1_1_1
{
    //runs

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        ReadInputFile fileI = new ReadInputFile();// read plain text file text file
        ArrayList<String> localList = fileI.readerNew();

        // Create a document and add a page to it
        try (PDDocument document = new PDDocument())
        {
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            document.addPage(page);

            // Create a new font1 object selecting one of the PDF base fonts
            PDFont font1 = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;//TIMES_ROMAN;
            PDFont font2 = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
            PDFont font3 = PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD;

            try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page))
            {

                //Creating PDImageXObject object
                PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("C:/PdfBox_Examples/CARD00.GIF", document);

                //**creating the PDPageContentStream object
                //PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
                //**Drawing the image in the PDF document           
                contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 100, 500, 50, 70);//1ST number is horizontal posn from left

                //****TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
                // Define a text content stream using the selected font1, moving the cursor and drawing the text "Hello World"
                contentStream.beginText();

                contentStream.setFont(font1, 11);

                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, 0);
                contentStream.setCharacterSpacing(0);
                contentStream.setWordSpacing(0);
                contentStream.setLeading(0);
                contentStream.setLeading(14.5f);// this was key for some reason

                contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700);// sets the start point of text

                System.out.println("localList.size= " + localList.size());//just checking within bounds during testing

                String line;
                int i;

                for (i = 0; i < 138; ++i)
                {
                    System.out.println(localList.get(i));
                    line = localList.get(i);

                    contentStream.drawString(line);
                    contentStream.newLine();
                }

                contentStream.endText();
                //******************************************************
                // Make sure that the content stream is closed:
                contentStream.close();
            }

            // Save the results and ensure that the document is properly closed:
            document.save("Hello World.pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

result output with text written on top of image:

[image: result output with text written on top of image]

Comment: improved formatting a little bit

Comment: you appear to have tried to add code using a different account. Please use the account you created the question with and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46848230/edit) the question itself to add the code.

Comment: The leading value sets the vertical move when you call `contentStream.newLine();`. So what you should do is to use an appropriate value when drawing your image. So just substract the leading (14.5) the needed times from your initial value (e.g. 700) and use that for drawImage.

Comment: *"small images which need to be inserted above the question"* and *"I want to place the images in line with the text"*... these sentences seem to contradict, or do I misinterpret the word "inline"?

Comment: yes mkl I meant between questions i.e.

Comment: Image below that the Question some text?  below that answer1 below that answer 2 below that answer 3. then below that an image for the next question

Comment: I've read the whole thing again... IMHO the only problem seems to be is that you can't decide where to put your images. You need to do these calculations yourself, i.e. there is no "cursor" that you can ask "where am I currently".

Answer (score 1):

As per this pdf box fix: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-738, transparency is preserved only when rgba is set.so if transparency is preserved it will look as inline with the other text rather than an overlay, so this could be a solution for your first part of the problem ie the overlay issue.

And this example helps you find how to compute the width occupied by a specific text and thus to calculate where to place the image next after the text:
https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/DetermineTextFitsField.java?revision=1749360&view=markup

Comment: My output should look like this

Comment: my pdf should have:-   /a small image/new line then begin text and end text/new line  /a small image/new line then begin text and end text/newline  /a small image/new line then begin text and end text/newline /a small image/new line then begin text and end text/newline /a small image/new line then begin text and end text/new line /a small image/new line then begin text and end text/ etc.        Its a multi choice exam where some questions have small images at the beginning. its a pity I can't attached an example

Comment: Is there any book which can help me as I find the apache site unhelpful for beginners

Comment: I suggest you delete and rewrite your question so that it is properly formatted. The things in your comments don't make sense because comments are not formatted.

Comment: my finished pdf should have:- 
[a small image loaded from a file]
1. What is in the image?
a. answer a
b. answer b
c. answer c

[a small image loaded from a file]
2. What is in the image?
a. answer a
b. answer b
c. answer c

[a small image loaded from a file]
3. What is in the image?
a. answer a
b. answer b
c. answer c

Comment: the comment field doesn't allow text formatting each sentence should be on a new line.

Comment: I cant remember how I added the code in my first question?

Comment: Put four spaces before the line.